# How do I change background of component mouse is hovering on?

Tags: java, swing, hover, listener, mouse

I have a chess grid with dimensions 7 x 6, each square has a background, I want that background to change hue to red as I hover on it, then return to normal as I hover on something else, how do I achieve this using the mouse listeners?

This is my mouse dragged listener:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
    if (chessPiece == null)
        return;

    // The drag location should be within the bounds of the chess board

    int x = me.getX() + xAdjustment;
    int xMax = chessBoard.getWidth() - chessPiece.getWidth();
    x = Math.min(x, xMax);
    x = Math.max(x, 0);

    int y = me.getY() + yAdjustment;
    int yMax = chessBoard.getHeight() - chessPiece.getHeight();
    y = Math.min(y, yMax);
    y = Math.max(y, 0);

    chessPiece.setLocation(x, y); //drags the piece as i move, i want to 
                                  //change the hue of the square/Jpanel
                                  //under my cursor as i move.
    Component c= chessBoard.getComponentAt(chessPiece.getX(),chessPiece.getY());

}
```

Square is an instance of `BackgroundPanel`

```
package model.gui;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*
 *  Support custom painting on a panel in the form of
 *
 *  a) images - that can be scaled, tiled or painted at original size
 *  b) non solid painting - that can be done by using a Paint object
 *
 *  Also, any component added directly to this panel will be made
 *  non-opaque so that the custom painting can show through.
 */
public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel
{
    public static final int SCALED = 0;
    public static final int TILED = 1;
    public static final int ACTUAL = 2;

    private Paint painter;
    private Image image;
    private int style = SCALED;
    private float alignmentX = 0.5f;
    private float alignmentY = 0.5f;
    private boolean isTransparentAdd = true;
Graphics g;
    /*
     *  Set image as the background with the SCALED style
     */
    public BackgroundPanel(Image image)
    {
        this(image, SCALED);
    }

    /*
     *  Set image as the background with the specified style
     */
    public BackgroundPanel(Image image, int style)
    {
        setImage( image );
        setStyle( style );
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    }

    /*
     *  Set image as the backround with the specified style and alignment
     */
    public BackgroundPanel(Image image, int style, float alignmentX, float alignmentY)
    {
        setImage( image );
        setStyle( style );
        setImageAlignmentX( alignmentX );
        setImageAlignmentY( alignmentY );
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    }

    /*
     *  Use the Paint interface to paint a background
     */
    public BackgroundPanel(Paint painter)
    {
        setPaint( painter );
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    }

    /*
     *  Set the image used as the background
     */
    public void setImage(Image image)
    {
        this.image = image;
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     *  Set the style used to paint the background image
     */
    public void setStyle(int style)
    {
        this.style = style;
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     *  Set the Paint object used to paint the background
     */
    public void setPaint(Paint painter)
    {
        this.painter = painter;
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     *  Specify the horizontal alignment of the image when using ACTUAL style
     */
    public void setImageAlignmentX(float alignmentX)
    {
        this.alignmentX = alignmentX > 1.0f ? 1.0f : alignmentX < 0.0f ? 0.0f : alignmentX;
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     *  Specify the horizontal alignment of the image when using ACTUAL style
     */
    public void setImageAlignmentY(float alignmentY)
    {
        this.alignmentY = alignmentY > 1.0f ? 1.0f : alignmentY < 0.0f ? 0.0f : alignmentY;
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     *  Override method so we can make the component transparent
     */
    public void add(JComponent component)
    {
        add(component, null);
    }

    /*
     *  Override to provide a preferred size equal to the image size
     */
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        if (image == null)
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        else
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }

    /*
     *  Override method so we can make the component transparent
     */
    public void add(JComponent component, Object constraints)
    {
        if (isTransparentAdd)
        {
            makeComponentTransparent(component);
        }

        super.add(component, constraints);
    }

    /*
     *  Controls whether components added to this panel should automatically
     *  be made transparent. That is, setOpaque(false) will be invoked.
     *  The default is set to true.
     */
    public void setTransparentAdd(boolean isTransparentAdd)
    {
        this.isTransparentAdd = isTransparentAdd;
    }

    /*
     *  Try to make the component transparent.
     *  For components that use renderers, like JTable, you will also need to
     *  change the renderer to be transparent. An easy way to do this it to
     *  set the background of the table to a Color using an alpha value of 0.
     */
    private void makeComponentTransparent(JComponent component)
    {
        component.setOpaque( false );

        if (component instanceof JScrollPane)
        {
            JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane)component;
            JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
            viewport.setOpaque( false );
            Component c = viewport.getView();

            if (c instanceof JComponent)
            {
                ((JComponent)c).setOpaque( false );
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Add custom painting
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //  Invoke the painter for the background

        if (painter != null)
        {
            Dimension d = getSize();
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setPaint(painter);
            g2.fill( new Rectangle(0, 0, d.width, d.height) );
        }

        //  Draw the image

        if (image == null ) return;

        switch (style)
        {
            case SCALED :
                drawScaled(g);
                break;

            case TILED  :
                drawTiled(g);
                break;

            case ACTUAL :
                drawActual(g);
                break;

            default:
                drawScaled(g);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Custom painting code for drawing a SCALED image as the background
     */
    private void drawScaled(Graphics g)
    {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, d.width, d.height, null);
    }

    /*
     *  Custom painting code for drawing TILED images as the background
     */
    private void drawTiled(Graphics g)
    {
           Dimension d = getSize();
           int width = image.getWidth( null );
           int height = image.getHeight( null );

           for (int x = 0; x < d.width; x += width)
           {
               for (int y = 0; y < d.height; y += height)
               {
                   g.drawImage( image, x, y, null, null );
               }
           }
    }

    /*
     *  Custom painting code for drawing the ACTUAL image as the background.
     *  The image is positioned in the panel based on the horizontal and
     *  vertical alignments specified.
     */
    private void drawActual(Graphics g)
    {
        Dimension d = getSize();
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        int width = d.width - insets.left - insets.right;
        int height = d.height - insets.top - insets.left;
        float x = (width - image.getWidth(null)) * alignmentX;
        float y = (height - image.getHeight(null)) * alignmentY;
        g.drawImage(image, (int)x + insets.left, (int)y + insets.top, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()` ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html